# How can I run this bash script Need to add two comment together

Tags: bash, alias

```
alias git-repo="xdg-open" + "git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g'| sed -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g'| sed -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g'"
```

I want to open the link in browser I can get the link with the second section of this script but i just need to add `xdg-open` like a prefix

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  What is the output of `git config ....` ?  FYI, `+` is not valid when defining an alias.

Comment: Why use an `alias`? Just use a function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two commands separated by a `;` in an alias:

```sh
alias e="echo 1; echo 2"
e
1
2
```

But it looks like you want to use the output of the `git config` as input to `xdh-open`. In that case you need to use `$(...)`. Merging the three `sed` commands int one gets:

```sh
alias git-repo="xdg-open $(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g' -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g')"
```

But if you define the alias like this, the `git config` runs at the time you define the alias, and you probably want that to happen when you actually use the alias. So put it in single quotes:

```
alias git-repo="xdg-open '$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g' -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g')'"
```

Like @KamilCuk said in the comment, if it gets more complicated, a shell script or function may be better:

```sh
function git_repo {
    url=$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g' -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g')
    echo "$url"
    xdg-open "$url"
}
```

You can put the function in e.g., `~/.bashrc` or any other file that you `source`.

As a script:

```
set -eu
url=$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g' -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g')
echo "$url"
xdg-open "$url"
```

This is easier to read and work with, your editor can do syntax highlighting, and [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can warn you if something looks off.

Comment: thank you bro atleast i use like this `alias git-repo="git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g'| sed -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g'| sed -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g'; xdg-open '$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g' -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g')'"` this gives firstly URL in terminal after redirected me. But is there any shorter solution is that while i use like this. Like declareted a variable like URL = "string" ??